# how can I get the base image url

Tags: version, google-cloud-dataproc

I am having an image version for dataproc image which is 1-4-41-debian10, how can I get the uri for such a base image? :)
I am aware that I can run

```
gcloud compute images list --project=cloud-dataproc --uri | grep '1-4-deb10'
```

which gives me list of uris for image 1.4 debian 10 but how can I now the specific uri for the previously mentioned image version?

Answer (score 2):

If you create a cluster with that version, then describe it, you'd see both the imageVersion and the imageUri:

Example:

```
$ gcloud dataproc clusters describe my-cluster --region us-central1 | grep -e imageUri -e imageVersion
    imageUri: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/cloud-dataproc/global/images/dataproc-2-0-deb10-20211021-060200-rc01
    imageVersion: 2.0.24-debian10
    imageUri: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/cloud-dataproc/global/images/dataproc-2-0-deb10-20211021-060200-rc01
```